# Why Rails deserializes snake case data structures but serializes camel case data structures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

It is one of my first Ruby on Rails project and it is weird for me to send JSON with properties written in snake case on my requests and receive JSON with properties written in camel case on my responses.

Here is an example of request payload:

```
{
  "end_point":"test"
}
```

And here is an example of response payload:

```
{
  "endPoint":"test"
}
```

Here is the code that consumes and returns the alike data structures above:
def create

```
def create
    @api = interactor.create(params[:organization_id], api_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: api_url(@api) }
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code that generates your JSON

Comment: @jumpingcode thanks for the interest! I've edited the question so you could grasp the idea on whats happening

Comment: @Motta : What does this line do: `@api = interactor.create(params[:organization_id], api_params)` what's `interactor` here? a model class? a method? what?

Comment: It is a service class, I keep logic inherent to persistence in the model and logic inherent to the business on the interactor.

Comment: I'm sending to the controller a JSON in the same format my ruby model, but I think the `format.json { render :show, ...` is converting it to camel case.

I think it would be nice for my controller to receive camel case and deserialize to the ruby model format, some kind of interceptor.

Comment: @Motta : See the updated revision. Also, "some kind of interceptor"? What does that even mean? It' unclear to me what exactly you're trying to do with `interceptor`.

Comment: @Surya : I would like to receive camelized data structures on every controller in my applicatiom, that's why I thought an interceptor could be a good solution.

In other technologies I've worked with when we want some common aspect in many places, like data structure conversion, an interceptor is a good call.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#camelize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize) method from `ActiveSupport`(which comes with Rails) like so:

```
attributes_hash = { "test_data" => "test" }
json_hash = Hash[attributes_hash.map {|k, v| [k.camelize(:lower), v] }]
#=> {"testData"=>"test"}
```

Now, you can convert it to JSON string:

```
p json_hash.to_json #=> "{\"testData\":\"test\"}"
```

**UPDATE**: You can override `serializable_hash` method in your model class(since you're not clear with what exactly `interceptor` is in your code, I assume you'd need to put this in the class whose object you're instantiating to send the data as JSON) like so -

```
def serializable_hash(options = nil)
  options ||= {}

  if options[:camelize]
    Hash[attributes.map {|k, v| [k.camelize(:lower), v] }]
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Now, you can do: `@api.to_json(:camelize => true)` and it'll convert attributes to camecase except the first character, i.e.: `endPoint`.

Comment: Hey Surya, thanks for the quick answer but it doesn't answer what I asked.

I'm working with requests and responses, I just ask rails to answer a controller or receive some parameters and then I get the described behavior.

Comment: @Motta : Idea is to change attributes when you're converting your object to json. If you can share what `interactor ` is in your code then I guess I can point you into a right direction. Is it a model or some pure ruby class?

Comment: I've edited the question including the controller that both consumes and serializes the data structure, it isn't a conversion neither an interactor

Comment: I don't want to do this in a specific model, I'd like to receive camlized data structures in this interceptor (or the like) and deserialize to my snake case ruby data structure. The response data structure format is ok and don't need any conversion.

Comment: Then override the above method in `ActiveRecord::Base` class instead of individual model.